# Iterating FindRoot to solve a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, programming, nonlinear, procedural-programming

I am new to *Mathematica* style programming, better at traditional programming.  I would like to know if I can create a table of results using `FindRoot`, where the solution from the current `FindRoot` call becomes the start point for the next `FindRoot` call.  I would like to create a `For` loop with a set number of iterations.

#### Update

In the comment section someone asked what I was trying to achieve with an iterated `FindRoot`.  What I am trying to solve is the following differential equation using numerical methods:

```
NDSolve[{Exp[y'[x]] + Exp[-y[x]] == 1, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}]
```

*Mathematica* does not like this equation, and gives me the error:

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.

I have not seen a differential equation like this before, but thought it would be interesting to see what kind of numerical solution it would give. My way around this is to use `FindRoot` and a finite difference equation to find `y[x]`.

```
FindRoot[Exp[(u1 - u0)/h] + Exp[-u0] == 1, {u1, u0}]
```

I start with `u0 = 1`, and `h = 0.1`.  I can then solve for `u1`.  I then use `u1` as the  new `u0` and use `FindRoot` again to find the next `u1`. That is where I need to iterate the `FindRoot` function.  If someone has a better idea I would appreciate it.  I will try the `Nest` function, and I saw another similar question on StackExchange elsewhere, and will try that solution too.

Comment: You are looking for the `Nest` family of functions. Se e.g. the documentation for `Nest` here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html

Comment: @MarcoB is correct, but why would you want to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: This is not difficult to do, what you describe with approach better than a loop one, but as it is described now it does not make sense. Indeed, `FindRoot ` already returns the result of a Newton iteration with a fixed precision. So, no use to iterate it further.  If you have in mind something more complex than a simple equation (or a system) to help we should see its explicit form.

Comment: When one poses a problem it is best to give an example piece of code (even if it is a simplified version of the actual problem). This has benefits both for those who answer and for the person who asked the question (it helps with communicating your problem).

Comment: presumably each `FindRoot` finds roots of a different system where we assume the last solution is a good initial guess to the current one. A simple `Table` is likely what you want.

Comment: Try `s = First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == Log[1 - Exp[-y[x]]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I noted in an earlier comment, the ODE to be solved can be rewritten as

```
eq = y'[x] == Log[1 - Exp[-y[x]]]
```

Then,

```
s = First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == Log[1 - Exp[-y[x]]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 5}];
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[y[x] /. s]], {x, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

where `Re[y]` is blue, and `Im[y]` is tan.  Because the ODE is singular at `y == 0`, it is natural to ask whether the solution is valid beyond that point.

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[(Exp[y'[x]] + Exp[-y[x]] - 1) /. s]], {x, 0, 5}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, "eq"}]
```

[image]

shows that it is.

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed answer.  You say that the second plot indicates that the solutions beyond the point y==0 are valid.  I don't know if this is an ODE or a Mathematica piece of information, but can you explain why the second graph shows that the validity?  What would the graph look like if it were not valid?

Comment: And what is the purpose of the ampersand symbol after the First function call.  In the Mathematica help, they do not use the ampersand.

Comment: @PMay  The second figure plots the ODE evaluated for the solution `s`.  If this solution were incorrect, the values shown in the second plot would be much larger.  In fact, you can solve the ODE with high `WorkingPrecision`, and the residual error shown in the second plot would be smaller still.  In answer to your second comment, `First@NDSolve[...]` is equivalent to `First[NDSolve[...]]`.  Look up [Prefix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prefix.html).  Thanks for accepting my answer.  Best wishes.

Comment: Just a remark. The plot of Re, Im is wrong. The function y is not singular in 1, its derivative is, y has a vertical drop. Yet the plot shows that y has a minimum at around `x=1.5`, thus implying that `y' =0` at that point.
That means 1-Exp[-y]=0 and of course that cannot happen unless `y=+Inf`.